# can we access key and value in the ordereddict in python.?

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I worked to access the item in ordered dictionary. `d` is the ordered dictionary:

```
print d.items()
```

Here the output is a pair. I want to access the key and value in this pair.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can unpack the key, value (a tuple) as below:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    print (key)
    print (value)
```

This works both on python 2 and 3.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value)
>   pairs).

Answer (score 5):

Each "pair" in `d.items()` is a tuple (ordered, immutable sequence) `(key, value)`. You can "unpack" the values in each tuple into separate names, for example in a `for` loop:

```
for key, value in d.items():
```

Comment: @user3243366 Yes it does works see [`class collections.OrderedDict([items])¶`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) Return an instance of a dict subclass, **supporting the usual dict methods**.